# Build multiple Visual Studio solutions with Github Actions

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, yaml, github-actions

I'm trying to build several solutions with Github Actions. I'm using a matrix strategy since I need to build for Release and Debug, in x64 and x86, however, I can't find how to use wildcards to build multiple solutions. I currently have this:

```
jobs:
samples-build-VS-2019:
runs-on: windows-2019

strategy:
  matrix:
    configuration: [Release, Debug]
    platform: [x86, x64]

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Setup MSBuild.exe
    uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.3
  
  - name: Use NuGet 5.2.0
    uses: nuget/setup-nuget@v1

  - name: Restore nuget packages for all solutions
    run: msbuild 'Samples/**/*.sln' /p:configuration=${{ matrix.configuration }} /p:platform=${{ matrix.platform }} /t:restore
  
  - name: Build all Sample solutions
    run: msbuild 'Samples/**/*.sln' /p:configuration=${{ matrix.configuration }} /p:platform=${{ matrix.platform }}
```

Unfortunately, that gives me a "MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist." error.
Is it even possible to do this? I need to do it like that because I need the CI to run on Pull requests that add new solutions/projects, as well as existing solutions.

Comment: See output of `msbuild /?`: it takes only one project file at a time. So if you want to build multiple you'll have to swap the invocation: list all projects and pipe each into msbuild. Don't know cmd syntax (or whatever the action's `run` uses) but in e.g. powershell you'd use something like `ls Samples -Recurse -File *.sln | %{& msbuild $_ /p....}`